# Fill jQuery Variable from serverside on load

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I was looking on internet for over 2 hrs now, trying to find simple example of how to fill jQuery Variable from serverside code on load of asp.net page.

What i have so far:

I have a button which call this jquery code:

```
    function GetListOfQuestions() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'UserProfile.aspx/getQuestions',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            error: OnAjaxError,
            success: AjaxSucceeded
        });
        //$.getJSON('UserProfile.aspx/getQuestions', {}, function (data) {
        //    alert(data);
        //});
    }

    function AjaxSucceeded(result) {

        alert(result);

    }
```

GetListOfQuestions calls serverside :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static List<Question> getQuestions(){

        var userGuid = (Guid)System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        IEnumerable<Question> list = Question.getQuestionsForUser(userGuid).Select(x => new Question
        {
            Uid = x.Uid,
            Content = x.Content
        });

        return list.ToList();
    }
```

result return an object if I alert it, so it must contain some kind of data, but I can't find any example of how I can retrieve data again on client side.

I'm not sure if what I am doing right now is right at all (I'm new to jQuery). So how can I retrieve data from result variable again?

Comment: get Firefox + firebug, use the console to view your object and its contents. far easier than debugging with alerts.

Comment: Just tryed it, very nice tool, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be better ways but this is one way I know of:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string getQuestions(){

        var userGuid = (Guid)System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        IEnumerable<Question> list = Question.getQuestionsForUser(userGuid).Select(x => new Question
        {
            Uid = x.Uid,
            Content = x.Content
        });

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(list.ToList())
    }
```

In your jQuery method, you can

```
result = $.parseJSON(data) ;
```

Do a `console.log(result)` to see how to iterate through result, should be just a for loop.

Comment: got this to work my way, but can any1 explain why this: console.log(alert(result.d[0].Content)); return content? where the hell does "d" comes from?!

Answer (score 0):

Put a hidden field on your page an set the variable value there, later read the hidden value from js.

Another option is to use ScriptManager.RegisterStart UpScript to write your variable directly as js to the page.